# psycopg2 rowcount for UPDATE is non-zero even without UPDATE changes

Tags: python, postgresql, sql-update, psycopg2

Following the [documentation of rowcount](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.rowcount), I should be able to get how many rows were updated with a UPDATE query e.g.

```
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute(
    'UPDATE users SET current_session_active=%(current_session_active)s WHERE users.id = %(id_1)s AND users.app = %(app_1)s',
     {'current_session_active': False, 'id_1': '884492906', 'app_1': 'Telegram'}
)
>>> cur.rowcount
1
```

I understand `cur.rowcount` = 1 as "the row you selected had the field `current_session_active` set to True, and now you updated it to False". I get confused when I repeat the query and I get the same value for `cur.rowcount`

```
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute(
    'UPDATE users SET current_session_active=%(current_session_active)s WHERE users.id = %(id_1)s AND users.app = %(app_1)s',
     {'current_session_active': False, 'id_1': '884492906', 'app_1': 'Telegram'}
)
>>> cur.rowcount
1
>>> cur.execute(
    'UPDATE users SET current_session_active=%(current_session_active)s WHERE users.id = %(id_1)s AND users.app = %(app_1)s',
     {'current_session_active': False, 'id_1': '884492906', 'app_1': 'Telegram'}
)
>>> cur.rowcount
1
```

**Being the two UPDATE identical, I would expect the second one to have cur.rowcount = 0**, since the data already got updated the first time and there is nothing to be updated the second time. Why do I get cur.rowcount = 1 the second (and the n-th) time?

Comment: So, you run the update query to set your desired value and get a value of 1, this means 1 row has been updated. When you run it again, it replaces `current_session_active = False` again with whatever previous value it contained, so you can do it `n` times, it'll update that column with `False` `n` times, so technically it is updating that row `n` times.

Comment: if you need your query to not update when the field is already `False`, you'll need to modify your query as: ```'UPDATE users SET current_session_active=%(current_session_active)s WHERE users.id = %(id_1)s AND users.app = %(app_1)s AND current_session_active = True',
     {'current_session_active': False, 'id_1': '884492906', 'app_1': 'Telegram'}```, so this will update the field once to False, giving you `1`, all future updates will give a `cur.rowcount = 0`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments by @Cavin Dsouza, to get `cur.rowcount = 1` only when the row value is modified you need to add a field in the `WHERE` clause to filter out rows that would not be updated.

```
>>> cur = conn.cursor()
>>> cur.execute(
    'UPDATE users SET current_session_active=%(current_session_active)s WHERE users.current_section_active = TRUE AND users.id = %(id_1)s AND users.app = %(app_1)s',
     {'current_session_active': False, 'id_1': '884492906', 'app_1': 'Telegram'}
)
>>> cur.rowcount 
1
>>> cur.execute(
    'UPDATE users SET current_session_active=%(current_session_active)s WHERE users.current_section_active = TRUE AND users.id = %(id_1)s AND users.app = %(app_1)s',
     {'current_session_active': False, 'id_1': '884492906', 'app_1': 'Telegram'}
)
>>> cur.rowcount
0
```

Comment: The row count you get from an UPDATE does not indicate the number of rows with data values changed. It tells you the number of rows that satisfy the WHERE condition.  As @CavinDsouza indicates if you want only those with different values you need that in the where clause.